# Post-increment x by n (n != 1)

Tags: c#, post-increment

So, if I execute the following code...

```
int x = 0;
Debug.WriteLine(x++);
Debug.WriteLine(x += 4);
Debug.WriteLine(x);
```

... I get 0, 5, and 5, respectively. What I'd like to get, however is 0, 1, and 5. Is there any way to do a post-increment by n in C#? Or do I have to write out the += as its own statement?

Just for context, what I'm actually doing is a bunch of BitConverter operations on a buffer, and it'd be really nice to have each one as a self-sufficient statement where the offset is incremented by the size of the data type being converted to. That way, if the buffer format is later changed, I can just add or remove the one line without having to worry about any of the surrounding code.

Comment: I would say it's not possible.

Comment: just so im clear, you want to post-increment by more than one?

Comment: using your example you will never ever get a `zero` and a `one` together out of those three `WriteLine`s.

Comment: Alden: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: `x++` is syntactic sugar for `x += 1`. This only works for `+1`, all others have to be done using `+= x`.

Comment: Mine it is not an answer, rather a question 'cos I don't understand the point. Why not PRE-increment (++x) in order to achieve the "one"?

Comment: @MarioVernari: then you'll never have `0` as output.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: No, `++x` is equivalent to `x += 1`.  `x++` can't be written using `+=`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: you're right, that distinction got lost on me.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: That distinction is the basis of this entire question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to abuse [Interlocked.Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3fxt78a(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the old value of a variable while at the same time replacing its value:

```
Debug.WriteLine(Interlocked.Exchange(ref x, x+4));
```

in other words, replace the value of variable `x` with `x + 4` but return the previous value of `x`.

**Edit:**

Disassembly shows this "increment by 4 and swap" is done in 4 instructions - no call needed at all, so performance should be good:

```
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref x, x + 4);
0000005e  mov         eax,dword ptr [rbp+2Ch] 
00000061  add         eax,4 
00000064  xchg        eax,dword ptr [rbp+2Ch] 
00000067  mov         dword ptr [rbp+28h],eax
```

The ***non-intuitive*** nature of this (and other) solutions probably boils down to the violation of the [CQS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) - we are mutating a variable and returning a value all at once, i.e. not something we should be doing in the mainstream.

Comment: This is very nice as well. Not intuitive, IMHO: you should spin a bit of brain in order to understand what the purpose of the line.

Comment: And I just learned something new. I'll give it a try and see how it performs compared to just using x += 4 as a separate operation. After all, I can always write that as a statement at the end of the line and tell StyleCop what to go do with itself when it complains about multiple statements on one line. :) This is basically the heart of a long-running operation, though, so whatever's fastest wins!

Comment: Just tested it and the performance was on par with writing a custom function, but not surprisingly, slower than just adding the extra x += 4.

Comment: Interlocked operations are potentially far more expensive than needed here.  Furthermore, they only work when one argument is a memory location.  In code like this, `x` ought to be in a register.  Not all 4 instruction sequences are created equal.  I'd venture to guess the performance approaches a custom function only if that function doesn't get inlined.

Comment: If you're going to call a method somewhere to do this job, I would rather go the route of creating a specialized method for this with a proper name.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know it's not possible. You could write your wrapper method like that:

```
static void ExecuteWithPost(ref int value, Action<int> operation, Func<int, int> postOperation)
{
    operation(value);
    value = postOperation(value);
}
```

and use it:

```
int i = 0;
ExecuteWithPost(ref i, x => Debug.WriteLine(x), x => x + 1);
ExecuteWithPost(ref i, x => Debug.WriteLine(x), x => x + 4);
ExecuteWithPost(ref i, x => Debug.WriteLine(x), x => x);
```

Prints what you want.

The wrapper method can be generic to make it work with types other than `int`:

```
static void ExecuteWithPost<T>(ref T value, Action<T> operation, Func<T, T> postOperation)
{
    operation(value);
    value = postOperation(value);
}
```

Comment: An upvote by me: I'd write something like this. I only don't like the "ref", and I'd prefer to return the updated value. Just tastes, though.

Comment: I thought of doing something like that, but figured it would probably add too much overhead. I like your solution, though, a lot more generic and elegant than mine would have been!

Answer (score 0):

Operator `++` is short form of `x = x + 1;` so using `+=` is not a bad idea:

If I understand you correctly:

```
int x = 0;
Debug.WriteLine(x++);  //return 0
Debug.WriteLine(x);  //return 1
Debug.WriteLine(x += 4);  //return 5
```

I would suggest you to use operator `+=` because any other way operator overloading or something else; will just be a overhead.

Comment: That's not a 'post-increment by 4' like x++, that's an increment by 4.